Possible to connect DC 12V P4 from PicoPSU to thermostat PWM controller DC input?
I'm thinking about powering i.a. this thermostat PWM fan controller with this 90W PicoPSU.
The PicoPSU has a P4 connector for DC 12V, but with only two wires instead of the usual four. (However, the two wires seem to be split at the end.) The fan controller has a DC 12V input. However, the controller input is plus and minus, while (afaik) the wires on the P4 are ground (black) and plus (yellow).
I thought about just removing the P4 connector and screwing the yellow +12V DC wire into the plus socket on the controller.
Is this even possible?

yes, that's possible, if i understand you. Have you considered using a PATA 2:1 splitter or extension cable to splice instead of the PSU? That would keep the more expensive part intact.

Not sure if I understand you correctly. The PATA connector, which afaik is the Molex format, is also on the PicoPSU, like the P4. At any rate, I assume it would be something like this splitter: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B0D1VLLGBY … but when I look at the Molex/PATA wiring, it's 2 * ground, 1 * +5V and 1 * +12V, so it would basically be the same, except I would lose +5V. For context, it would be part of a setup that I have envisioned here: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/mac-mini-as-home-server-with-add2psu-picopsu-etc-for-powering-external-sata-storage-case-fans.3861782/
